# Event not changing the state of the label react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Sorry i'm new to unit testing and i'm stuck on this.

I'm just testing the onClick of a "Show more" button.

> Total size = 16 items, Page size = 15 items

so if I clicked the button, it should add 1 item to the currentResult

```
test('Show more button click works successfully', () => {
const state = {
search: {
  ...initialState.search,
  mainResult: SearchData.test.large,
  currentResult: SearchData.test.large.slice(0, 15),
  currentCount: 15,
  currentTotal: 16,
},
};

store = mockStore(state);
const { getByTestId } = render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <SearchListing {...props} />
 </Provider>
);
const showMoreBtn = getByTestId('search-listing-result-footer-btn');

expect(getByTestId('search-listing-result-footer-label')).toHaveTextContent('Showing 15 of 16 results');

userEvent.click(showMoreBtn);

expect(getByTestId('search-listing-result-footer-label')).toHaveTextContent('Showing 16 of 16 results');
});
```

Show more function, I'm chunking the mainResult so if I click the show more, I'll just add the next chunk to currentResult.

```
 const showMore = () => {
const newPageCount = pageCount + 1;
const newResult = [...currentResult, ...resultsChunk[newPageCount]];
dispatch(searchActions.showMore({ currentResult: newResult, currentCount: newResult.length }));
setPageCount(newPageCount);
};
```

Error message:

```
Expected element to have text content:
  Showing 16 of 16 results
Received:
  Showing 15 of 16 results
```

How can I update the mockStore after onClick? or is there any other way.

Comment: Please show the complete, minimal, reproducible code of the component

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2 - Its just a list of item with label at the bottom showing the count 'Showing $currentCount of $totalCount results'. As you can see in the error message, i'm expecting the label to change from 15 to 16 when I clicked the 'Show more' button.

Comment: Rather than using `getByTestId(...)` have you tried using `await findByTestId(...)`? To make sure the state changes happen before checking the value has changed.